# IP packet forwarding in Debian

Tags: debian, networking, routing, forwarding

I have a physical network set up with machines A←–→B←–→C.  IP and Ethernet configurations are summarized as following:

> A(eth0: 10.10.10.2) ←—→ (eth0: 10.10.10.3)B(eth1: 192.168.0.3) ←—→ (eth1: 192.168.0.2)C

I would like to send a UDP packet from A to C. 
A `tcpdump` of the packet looks like: `10.10.10.2:10000-->192.168.0.2:10001` (10000 or 10001 are the port numbers).  Of course the packet must go through B, coming in at `eth0` of B and going out through `eth1`.

B's routing table is already configured as subnet 192.168.0.0/24 to `eth1`.  And `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is 1.

`tcpdump` on B confirms that the UDP packet can be received at `eth0`.  But `eth1` has nothing (neither for C), which means the packet is not correctly forwarded. (There is not any dropping policy by `iptables` at B.)

I recreated the topology on virtual machines, and it works. But on real physical machines, it is not working.  I also tried to write a simple kernel module using `netfilter` which does `printk("some messages")` whenever it detects an incoming UDP packet with destination port, say, 10001 (as previous example), but still the Linux kernel does not print anything.

PS. B's OS is Debian 6.0.10 (squeeze).

I would very much appreciate it if somebody can shed some light on the problem.